# C# Http server requests routing

Tags: c#, design-patterns, httpserver

I'm writing HTTP server using HttpListener, that would manage following requests. Each of them should return corresponding JSON object.

```
GET /command1/command2/command3
GET /command1/<ip-port>/command3
GET /command4/command3
GET /command5/
```

and so on...
How should I manage this branching of commands?
It seems to me I can easily deal with this using regex. Or maybe I should choose some pattern like State?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [Grapevine](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Grapevine/), which has this functionality built in. I'm the author of the library, but it's [open source](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine), so you can see how I manage routing by reviewing the source code (see src/Grapevine/Server). Or you can just use the library if it to meets your needs.

https://sukona.github.io/Grapevine/en/getting-started.html